# How to define interdependance between variables in scipy optimization (python 2.7)?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I need to optimize a complex function consisting of several elements which dependents on each other in a way like sum of xi=1 and 0<=xi<=1.

So I use scipy optimize.minimize with bounds.

But Idon't know how specify interdependence of xi. I use additional variable (x100) and have the bounds for it as (0, 0) and following condition within a functinon x100=1-x1-x2-x3-x4-x5.

Unfortunately the result doesn't work properly. I need to change `def arg` but I don't know how

How could I specify interdependance between xi (in order to `sum_x`=1)?

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from numpy import random, mean, var, std

def arg(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x100):
    x100=1-x1-x2-x3-x4-x5
    r = mean(x1*x2*x3*x4*x5)*std(x1+x2-x3+x4-x5)
    return r

def new_arg(x):
    return -arg(*x)


fun = new_arg
x0 = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5,\
    0.0)
res = minimize(fun, x0, method='SLSQP', bounds = ((0, 1),(0, 1), (0, 1),\
                                             (0, 1),(0, 1),(0, 0)))
kpi_opt = res.x
sum_x=res.x[0]+res.x[1]+res.x[2]+res.x[3]+res.x[4]

print 'kpi_opt',kpi_opt
print 'sum of xi = ',sum_x
```

Comment: Try and give a [minimal coding example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - spitting out your entire code bore people who want to help you. narrow it down.

Comment: @ Korem, thanks for your feedback. I've changed my question.

Comment: Did you try to put x100 in the arg return?

Comment: @user189, now I try it but it doesn't I need. I neen to know maximum of r,  with condition x1+x2+x3+x4+x5=1 and every x in range 0<=xi<=1

Comment: There is an example of such constraint on this page. http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html

Comment: @user189, thank you! that's what I need. I missed it because constraint example given there wasn't relevant. But now I tred different variants, and one works right.

Answer (score 1):

In you case, I think you want to further define a equality function constrain by `f_eqcons` parameter. It need to be a callable function and it should return 0 (or an array containing only 0s) in a successfully optimized problem. Following your minimal example:

```
import scipy.optimize as ss
def f(x):
    x1, x2, x3, x4, x5=x
    return -np.mean(x1*x2*x3*x4*x5)*np.std(x1+x2-x3+x4-x5)

x0=(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5)

def eq_f(x):
    x1, x2, x3, x4, x5=x
    return sum(x)

res=ss.fmin_slsqp(f, x0, f_eqcons=eq_f, bounds = ((0, 1),(0, 1), (0, 1),(0, 1),(0, 1)))
```

result:

```
Optimization terminated successfully.    (Exit mode 0)
            Current function value: -0.0
            Iterations: 1
            Function evaluations: 8
            Gradient evaluations: 1
In [11]:

res
Out[11]:
array([  0.00000000e+00,   5.55111512e-17,   0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00])
```